# How to use mergeMap to chain the service calls?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have the first API request (with http get) returns a set of data, and that data is required to call the subsequent API request (http post).

```
this.service1['get-info'].get().subscribe(data => {
 this.info = data.body;
 },
 error => console.log(error),
 ()=> {
 this.service2['send-email']['post']({body: this.info})
 .subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data);
   },
   error => console.log(error),
   () => {
      this.id = 0;
    });
   }
 );
```

Because an Observable has next, error and completed blocks. I put the second service into the completed block of the first service. It is anti-pattern. So how can I rewrite the code by using mergeMap?

Comment: Could you build a simple stackblitz that demonstrates your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do it the way the docs describe.

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap#example

You can't call onError() until you subscribe, however you can catch the error and pass it up to the outer Observable. You can catch the error using a method named.... *drum roll*... catchError() !!!

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

You can pipe this method into your Observable sequence. Something like:

```
this.service1.get().pipe(
  catchError(value => of('some message: ' + value))
  mergeMap(nextValue => some mapping logic here)
);
```

could work.

### Additional Explanation:

You're either slipping on `.pipe()` or `.mergeMap()`, or both.
If you understand how to use both individually, using them together is trivially easy.

`pipe()` is simply a newer way of calling Observable operators because the old way of dot-chaining involved patching the Observable prototype and it caused mass hysteria. `pipe()` replaced dot-chaining out of necessity to keep the Observable namespace/developer headspace cleaner.

And `.mergeMap()` is just a way to take an observable stream of n-number of nested levels and flatten it to n-1 levels deep, applying a mapping function as you flatten.

It is akin to Array.prototype.flatMap() if you know how to flatten an array.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

In this case, *your* mapping function is just a call the other service method that returns an Observable.

```
.mergeMap((service1ReturnedValue) => { 
   return this.service2.someServiceMethodThatReturnsAnObservable(service1ReturnedValue));
})
```

Comment: I hate me that I still don't understand it. I would like the whole answer code which matches my original code.

Comment: Well I love that you are about to start believing in yourself more, right now. Go you!

I updated my answer with some explanation.

Comment: So in the original `Completed` block, there is no place to do in your code? Also I assume your `catchError` is the replacement of the original `error` block? Finally the original the second `error` block, how to implement it in your new code?

Comment: `catchError()` catches the nested onError() instance and throws it up, so you can use the onError() callback of the outermost Observable so that you can handle all the errors in one place.

Comment: So how to handle the original `Completed` block?

Comment: that part probably won't change. So like normal, just .`subscribe()`! (after the `.pipe()`) `.pipe("catchError() and mergeMap() code goes here").subscribe(results => console.log(results))`

Comment: Can you rewrite the whole code so I can easily follow?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this,

```
`this.yourFirstService(data).pipe(
  map(res => // do what ever you want to do which first reques's response),
  mergeMap(() => this.yourSecondService())).subscribe( finalResponse => {

  });`
```

You need to call first service and then map it's response so you can do what ever you do with first service's response and then mergeMap second service. So this way you can resolve you issue.

Comment: Not sure `data` in your first service. Is it parameters passed to the service? Please clarify it.

Comment: `data`  is parameters which you want to pass in service. like in POST method you need to pass `data` it is option. based on you service call.

Comment: Let me give you example .
 this.service1.get().pipe(
      map(res => // do what ever you want to do which first request's response),
      mergeMap(() => this.service2['send-email']['post']({body: this.info}))).subscribe( finalResponse => {
      });
    );